# How to show some different kinds of pictures on fpga board by using verilog with VGA

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm trying to do my school's project, and one of functions that I want to do is showing different kinds of picture when press different buttons. And as I know, I've to load different pictures in the memory. I'm now trying to load two different pictures and showing one of them. However, as it worked fine when I was trying with only one picture but show noting when I was trying with two pictures. Really hope someone can help me!!! The following are my codes.

```
module top(
input clk,
input rst,
output [3:0] vgaRed,
output [3:0] vgaGreen,
output [3:0] vgaBlue,
output hsync,
output vsync
 );

wire [11:0] data;
wire clk_25MHz;
wire clk_22;
wire [16:0] pixel_addr;
wire [11:0] pixel;
wire valid;
wire [9:0] h_cnt; //640
wire [9:0] v_cnt;  //480
wire [11:0] data_1;
wire [16:0] pixel_addr_1;
wire [11:0] pixel_1;
wire valid_1;
wire [9:0] h_cnt_1; //640
wire [9:0] v_cnt_1;  //480

assign {vgaRed, vgaGreen, vgaBlue} = (valid==1'b1) ? pixel:12'h0;

 clock_divisor clk_wiz_0_inst(
  .clk(clk),
  .clk1(clk_25MHz),
  .clk22(clk_22)
);

mem_addr_gen mem_addr_gen_inst(
.clk(clk_22),
.rst(rst),
.h_cnt(h_cnt),
.v_cnt(v_cnt),
.pixel_addr(pixel_addr)
);


blk_mem_gen_0 blk_mem_gen_0_inst(
  .clka(clk_25MHz),
  .wea(0),
  .addra(pixel_addr),
  .dina(data[11:0]),
  .douta(pixel)
);


mem_addr_gen mem_addr_gen_inst_1(
    .clk(clk_22),
    .rst(rst),
    .h_cnt(h_cnt_1),
    .v_cnt(v_cnt_1),
    .pixel_addr(pixel_addr_1)
    );


    blk_mem_gen_1 blk_mem_gen_1_inst(
      .clka(clk_25MHz),
      .wea(0),
      .addra(pixel_addr_1),
      .dina(data_1[11:0]),
      .douta(pixel_1)
    ); 


vga_controller   vga_inst(
  .pclk(clk_25MHz),
  .reset(rst),
  .hsync(hsync),
  .vsync(vsync),
  .valid(valid),
  .h_cnt(h_cnt),
  .v_cnt(v_cnt)
);      
endmodule
```

Since it can work in the right way using only one picture, I think the module vga_controller, clock_divisor, mem_addr_gen, and blk_mem_gen_0 won't have problems in the design of the module, therefore, I only post the details of my top module. Thanks!!

Comment: What happens when you comment out the `...inst_1` circuits?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, your intention is to instantiate a `mem_addr_gen` and `blk_mem_gen` for each image you'd like to display. Presuming your system works for the one-image case, then here are some suggestions:

1. As long as all your images are the same size (640x480, apparently), you likely only need one instance of the `mem_addr_gen` module - you should be able to share the `h_cnt`, `v_cnt`, and `pixel_addr` over the set of `blk_mem_gen`'s.
2. You'll need some way to select from your set of images.

Consider the following:

```
reg [2:0] activeImage; //between 0 and 7
wire [11:0] pixel_out [7:0]; // pixel outputs from the blk_mem_gen
wire [11:0] pixel;

assign {vgaRed, vgaGreen, vgaBlue} = (valid==1'b1) ? pixel:12'h0;
assign pixel = pixel_out[activeImage];

blk_mem_gen_0 blk_mem_gen_0_inst(
  .clka(clk_25MHz),
  .wea(0),
  .addra(pixel_addr),
  .dina(data[11:0]),
  .douta(pixel_out[0])
);
...
```

This will assign whichever image is "active" (from 0-7, in this case) to the VGA.

3. Lastly, you'll want a way to change which image is being displayed.

This is more dependent on you implementation, but as an example:

```
input button;
input clk;
input rst;
reg buttonPrev; //previous button value
reg [2:0] activeImage; //between 0 and 7
reg [2:0] nextImage;

always@(posedge clk) begin
    buttonPrev <= button;
    if (rst) begin //reset
         activeImage <= 0;
         next_image <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        if (button && !buttonPrev) //button was just pressed
            nextImage <= nextImage + 1;
        if (h_cnt == 0 && v_cnt == 0) // starting a new frame
            activeImage <= nextImage;
    end
end
```

In this code, we increment `nextImage` once for each time the button is pressed (and holding the button down doesn't continue to increment). Then, when a new frame is started (`h_cnt` and `v_cnt` are both 0), we update the `activeImage` to the desired `nextImage`. It only updates at the start of an frame to avoid changing the image midway through drawing it.

Comment: NB: for 3, using `h_cnt == 639 && v_cnt == 479` might be more correct, depending on the timing of your system.